# Expected value of trials to obtain a red ball in a box of white balls.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, balls-in-bins

I have a problem that involves a box containg N balls, one of which is red and the rest of which (N-1) are white. The question involves finding the expected value and variance for the number of trials to obtain the red ball in the case that (a) the balls are replaced and the case (b) the balls are not replaced.

For (a) I said that
$$P(X=1) = \frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(X=2) = \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n^2}$$
$$P(X=3) = \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^3}$$
etc.

So that:
$$E(X) = \sum xP(X=x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^{k}}$$

For (b) I said that:
$$P(X=1) = \frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(X=2) = \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(X=3) = \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-2} = \frac{1}{n}$$
etc.

So that:
$$E(X) = \sum xP(X=x) = \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{1}{n}$$

So originally when I was writing this question I had obtained the same result for both but then found an error in my ways. Instead I'll ask is this working correct? Any assistance is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to (i) is slightly wrong as with replacement you can require more than $n$ selections so it should be $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^{k}}$ but this can be simplified to $n$.  An easier approach is to solve $E[X]=1 + \dfrac{n-1}{n}E[X]$, since this is a geometric distribution.

Your answer to (ii) is correct but this can be simplified to $\dfrac{n+1}{2}$, since you are just looking at the average of the possible values from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for your response, I have a couple of additional questions if that's ok.

My first question relates to part (a) and how you are able to tell that this can be simplified to n. Also, I had no seen this easier approach you mentioned, do you know of any any reference material I might be able to read to find more out about this?

My next question relates to finding the variance for each part. 

For (a) I'm not sure how you would simplify given that:

$$E(X) = \sum x^2P(X=x) - (\sum xP(X=x))^2$$

Where $$\sum x^2P(X=x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^k}$$

Comment: Similarly for part (b) would I be correct in doing:

$$E(X) = \sum x^2P(X=x) - (\sum xP(X=x))^2 $$

$$= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n} - (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n})^2 $$

$$= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n} -  \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2$$

$$= \frac{1}{6} (n+1) (2 n+1) - \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$$

$$=\frac{n^2-1}{12}$$

Comment: For (a) you have the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) - look at the left column of the infobox using $p=\frac{1}{n}$: you have $E[X^2] = 2n^2-n$ and $Var(X)= n^2-n$.  For (b) you have a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) with $E[X^2] = \frac16(2n^2+3n+1)(2n+1)$ and $Var(X)=\frac{1}{12}(n^2-1)$ as you seem to say say